# Display different icons depending on field value

Tags: 8

I am trying to produce a result that requires PHP code to evaluate whether a Drupal 8 node field is a "x", an "f", a "m", a "h", or an "l".

Thanks to some help on an earlier question, I've accomplished my task (to replace the value with a useful icon) when the value is binary: if it exists, show this. If it's empty, show nothing. I've done this via CSS.

Now I'd like to extract the actual value of the node field, and display different icons based on its value.

I am not planning to do this via a function, but rather by code on the node itself.  Is there some syntax I can use within the php that will extract this?  So that I can have the equivalent of:

```
$price = $node[field][value];
```

then I'd do:

```
if ($price == "m") { // use icon X }
else if ($price == "h") { // use icon Y };
```

Thank you for any and all help/suggestions!

Comment: You can’t do php in a twig file. The proper way to do this is set the icon value from a preprocess_node hook in the .theme file.

Comment: Thank you, Kevin.  I am fairly new...was hoping to do this in the node Content itself using php.  Is that just silly?  Impossible?  

Alternately, is there a good place to start learning what a preprocess_hook is and how to use it? 

My other alternative would be to split the field into its various values and just do it binarily -- "if exists, rewrite the background-image" otherwise display none.  If that's easier in my case, I could opt for that.  It would suck to add 6 fields into the node but I don't have thousands of nodes...30 or 40 or so.  If that's the easiest, I'll do it that way.

Comment: Keeping php code in the database is bad practice and never advised. This is pretty easy with one list field and a switch statement

Comment: @Kevin, thanks for sticking with me on this.  Is there a way to implement this that's relatively newbie friendly?  I've heard of hooks as a term but have never used them.  Where's the best place to start?  

Also, in your comment, the "pretty easy with..." can you give me the syntax for how this would be done?  Are you talking about something within a .theme file?  Or (inadvisable as it may be) doing it on the page itself.  If so, I think the "list field" part might be what I'm missing -- how do I do that part?  Again, thank you in advance for any additional info/help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This only requires one field. It sounds like it is a list (text) field to me.

This should be done as a new variable to the node template by way of using `hook_preprocess_node` in your `MYTHEME.theme` (replace any instance of MYTHEME with your actual themes name, i.e. `bartik`) file. Here is an example:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  $type = $variables['node']->getType();

  if ($type == 'NODE_TYPE') {
    $price = $variables['node']->get('field_name')->value;

    switch ($price) {
      case "m":
        $variables['custom_icon'] = 'icon1';
        break;

      case "h":
        $variables['custom_icon'] = 'icon2';
        break;

      case "x":
        $variables['custom_icon'] = 'icon3';
        break;

      case "f":
        $variables['custom_icon'] = 'icon4';
        break;

      case "l":
        $variables['custom_icon'] = 'icon5';
        break;

      default:
        $variables['custom_icon'] = FALSE;
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

Then, create a `node--NODE-TYPE.html.twig` file, where `NODE-TYPE` is the machine name (bundle) of the node in question (ex. `article`, `page`, `product`).

In this file, you now have a new variable available to use, which would be output with:

```
{% if custom_icon %}
  {{ custom_icon }}
{% endif %}
```

If no value, or value does not match whats expected, the switch statement will set the variable to FALSE so you can check in Twig if you should output it or not.

Comment: Thank you very much, @Kevin!  I was writing my comment simultaneously.  I will try to implement this and might get back with questions if I can't figure it out!  Again, thank you!

Comment: And just curious:  this above code will NOT work as php on the page, right?  It's only usable through implementing in the .theme of my theme?

Comment: You cannot put PHP in Twig template files, nothing will happen. As you can see from the code, the variable will only be created for the node type you are targeting. `hook_preprocess_node` is the standard way of manipulating or creating new variables for the node template. See: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21node%21node.module/function/template_preprocess_node/8.7.x

Comment: This is exactly how I would solve the issue. I tried looking for tutorials, but most are outdated (and linking to random blogs is discouraged here, because we can't guarantee the link would work in the future). I would recommend picking up one of the Drupal 8 Theming books or checking out drupalize.me on theming.

Comment: thank you very much.  I will take a stab at this and if I get it working I'll be sure to circle back and give this a bright green checkmark.  If not I'll likely have a few more questions.  I really appreciate your adding the additional explanations (for example, "replace with Bartik...").  While I would like to of course learn the underlying concepts of theming, my hope is to get this up and working as soon as possible.  But I did try (before posting) to find good D8 tutorials on something like this and it seemed hard.  I'll check the book too.  Thanks again!

Comment: Be sure to copy `node.html.twig` as the basis for your node `node--` file mentioned above too, then just fill in the icon where you need it (mentioned as `{{ custom_icon }}`).

Comment: Okay, with trepidation I leaped into the .theme file and made a new node--review.html.twig for the new content.  

First, with or without the twig file, the code above seems to hang.  I just get white blank page instead of my site.  Removing the code and resaving works fine.  Is there any chance I've got something wrong in the syntax?  Or a typo?

I've got the machine name for the review ('review') and replaced NODE_TYPE with that.  I also swapped the theme in the name of the function (and am editing the .theme file for my default theme).  I tried changing the "field_name" to "field_price"

Comment: It's asking if I want to move this to chat but I feel this is still germane to the discussion.  I changed "field_name" to "field_price" and then switched back.  Is there anything else I need to do?  Like run a update script or such?  Clear a cache?  Or could there be something wrong in the code?

My other questions is in the node--review.html.twig file, I don't really see where I can USE this variable.  I just see a small "{{content}} block.  How do I dig deeper into that content part so that I can place the field where I want it to be?

Comment: (Happy to move to chat if that's preferred.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87900/discussion-between-user1149499-and-kevin).

Comment: Thank you again, @Kevin, for the help, your time explaining, and the clearly written code.  Unfortunately I tried several things, first putting the code in as written, then realizing that there was already an identically-named function, so I tried to add the inner code to the existing one.  In both cases I ended up with a site that simple turned white. 

So for now, I've taken a different track:  I'm forgoing the icons entirely and just writing out "High" for "h," "Low" for "l," and so on...and displaying the field values.  It's much less than what I'd hoped but will do for now.  Thank you!

Comment: so of all crazy things, I went back to this and tried something different and got it to work.  It was much simpler than I thought, so I'm really amazed and grateful you took the time. I'm marking this with a green check.  Ideally I'd like to have these variables inside the {{ content }} section, but that seems like a different animal...for now, this helps a lot and I'll be on my way.  :-)

Comment: `content` is a render array and very different frommcreating a printing a simple variable. While possible, this is the simplest approach to your problem without getting too deep in the weeds. It gives you a starting point to figure out how to refactor and refine it for different, deeper, richer or simpler solutions.

Comment: Okay, @Kevin, thank you again for the info.  I guess my question is more basic then, because there are a vast array of incredible Drupal sites out there with stunning variety in the content, its display, its placement...so how does one DO that sort of thing?  I've poked around and it seems it's NOT done with CSS (though you can use Asset Injector if need be), and it's clearly NOT done with typical HTML, and it's NOT done in the content array...but it must be done somehow.  Are there good developer modules that offer easier access or tools?  These icons lie outside the Content, the others are

Comment: ...inside it.  I have a Title, (node name), then a field in the Content with a Subtitle, then below that the icons that are binary (mentioned above).  Can I use this {{ custom_icon }} within the {{ Content }} somehow?  Or does Drupal development mainly focus elsewhere?  I'm sorry if that's a very basic question but maybe I'm just coming at it from the mind of a HTML/CSS code writer and this is all handled extremely differently in Drupal.

Comment: That’s probably suited for a new question, but outputting {{ content }} is everything - you don’t have to do that and instead you can break it out field by field in the template ex. `{{ content.field_price }}` would print only that field value. Too much to type in a comment.

Comment: Thank you, Kevin, I'll ask in a new question as you suggest!

Answer (score 0):

To display different icons depending on some field values you can simply make use of [`template_preprocess_field`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_field/8.2.x). Get the field value and add a CSS class accordingly. And the rest is just CSS.

```
/**
 * Implements template_preprocess_field__FIELD_NAME().
 *
 * @param array $variables
 */
function MYTHEME_preprocess_field__field_price(&$variables) {

  // Get the field value.
  $value = $variables['element'][0]['#markup'];

  // Do whatever else you need to do with $value.
  // ksm($value); ...
  // ...

  // And then append $value as a new CSS class to the field wrapper.
  $variables['attributes']['class'][] = $value;
}
```

Install the [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) sub-module Kint to let `ksm()`
 pretty-print the value for debugging.

---

Note, depending on the field type you used, the value may be hidden in `$variables['element'][0]['#text'];` or `$variables['element'][0]['#value'];` or something else. Simply check what's inside `$variables['element']` via `ksm($variables['element'])`, first.

Comment: This is another way to do it, but since I wasn’t sure where this will be output I listed the node preprocess. It should be noted that if this icon displays outside of the context of the field output, that’s the way to go. If the icon shows alongside the price within the fields own markup, then this is more fitting.

Comment: @Kevin – Absolutely. +1 for your answer. I avoid editing templates whenever possible. Even on the node level, if the icon should be displayed in the context of another field (maybe price field) of the same node, I'd use prep_field__price, load the parent object, get the icon field value, and append that as class to the price field.